# Where is the memory error in this code?

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc

Someone asked me to write this code as an exercise in C. When they looked over what I had written, they immediately told me that there was a huge error regarding memory management. Being a simple exercise, they wanted me to find and fix this error. There must be a gap in my knowledge, or I must be overlooking something very obvious, because I cannot for the life of me find it. If someone could help me figure it out, I would be very grateful.

Here is the code:

```
char int_to_char(int number){
    if (number > 9) return (char)(((int)'A') + number - 10);
    else return (char)(((int)'0') + number);
}

int change_base(char* output, int buffer_size, int decimal_number, int base){
    //check for valid parameters
    if((base < 2) || (base > 26)) return -1;        //range error

    //ready variables
    int output_i = 0;
    int tmp_string_i = 0;
    int dividend;
    char remainder;
    char * tmp_string = calloc(buffer_size, sizeof(char));
    memset(output, '\0', buffer_size*sizeof(char));

    //check for negative input
    if(decimal_number < 0){
        output[0] = '-';
        dividend = -decimal_number;
        output_i++;
    }
    else dividend = decimal_number;

    //find digits
    while(dividend / base != 0){
        remainder = int_to_char(dividend % base);
        dividend = dividend / base;
        tmp_string[tmp_string_i] = remainder;
        tmp_string_i++;
        if(tmp_string_i + 1 > buffer_size){     //+1 for the extra negative sign
            free(tmp_string);
            return -2;      //buffer size error
        }
    }
    //add last digit to string
    remainder = int_to_char(dividend);
    tmp_string[tmp_string_i] = remainder;

    //copy tmp_string to output in reverse order
    for(; tmp_string_i >= 0; tmp_string_i--){
        output[output_i] = tmp_string[tmp_string_i];
        output_i++;
    }
    free(tmp_string);
    return 0;
}
```

Also worthy of note, I have run this code through Valgrind to find any common memory mistakes, but it reports no errors. I don't know very much about the advanced features or nuances of Valgrind.

Lastly, I would be very happy for any comments on how I could improve the overall effectiveness and readability of this code.

Comment: "huge error" is actually not very specific (and not even objective), so you should ask that person what they think is wrong with your code. The only thing I can see that would bother me just by looking at it, is that you don't check whether `calloc` actually succeeded.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am beginning to think they may have made a mistake. Also, I am sensing from the downvotes that this is not a very good question (ha!). Should I have posted this over at codereview?

Comment: Have you actually tried running the code to see what happens?

Comment: Yes, Code Review might have been a better choice, as SO is aimed more towards helping solve specific problems (say if you had a runtime error or a compiler error you could not figure out), rather than trying to find errors (or even "huge errors" which are not as apparent as someone actually thought)

Comment: @dbc, on my machine, it works as expected (at least in all the test cases I tried). Valgrind returns no error messages.

Comment: @Ben Creighton - if the code passes all your unit tests and there are no errors reported with code analysis tools then submitting to code review makes sense.  For instance, `memset` to `\0` after `calloc` is redundant.

Comment: @Ben Creighton I upvoted your question because I do not think that  it is a bad question.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If to say about one "huge error" then this error is the awful code itself.:)l
So if there are other errors then in fact they do not deserve to be discussed until the code will be rewritten.

For example do you know that if some integral number is negative then after statement like this

```
number = - number;
```

the number can be as before negative?:)

I think that "somebody" meant by "huge error" that your string is not zero-treminated.:) Consider a situation wnen the number has only one digit and buffer_size is equal to 1

And why does buffer_size have type int instead of size_t?

Also in my opinion it is a bad idea to allocate additional buffer for such a conversion.